# Deciding between Mobile/Desktop Version and redirection to correct Module

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular6

I was wondering what the best ways are to optimize my app for mobile devices.

I know I can do a css media query but I'm not talking about that.

1. How do I check if I'm on mobile? Which properties do I check to make sure I'm on mobile? I would probably use the screen width like this:

`if (window.innerWidth < 450)`

Is that the proper way?

2. What do I do when I wan't to change the whole layout of my app, maybe use different components and routing when on mobile? The best solution I came up with is creating two different lazy modules for mobile and desktop which load different, for its platform optimzed components. I like this solution but how do I direct the user to the correct module?

   `if (window.innerWidth < 450) {
       this.router.navigateByUrl('/mobile');
   } else {
       this.router.navigateByUrl('/desktop');
   }`

This code works but the problem with it is, event when I'm on the correct module path (desktop/mobile) and navigate to a deeper path like `/mobile/pageX`, I get redirected to `/mobile`. So this doesn't seem like a nice solution

Answer (score 0):

I like to use this for getting max and min width of the screen size:

```
function something() {
    if (x.matches) { // If media query matches

       // do something

    } else if (Y.matches){

        //do something

    }
}

var x = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 425px)")
var Y = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 426px)")
```

Comment: for part 2 of your question, im not sure what to do

Comment: Thanks thats a nice way to query the width.